# Enforcing dynamic polymorphic calls with general parent type input arguments

Tags: java, dynamic, polymorphism, parent

I am trying to use polymorphism to enable different processing of an object based on its class, as follows:

```
public class GeneralStuff {
    private int ID;
}

public class IntStuff extends GeneralStuff {
    private int value;

    public void setValue(int v)
    {
        value = v;
    }

    public int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
}

public class DoubleStuff extends GeneralStuff {
    private double value;

    public void setValue(double v)
    {
        value = v;
    }

    public double getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
}

public class ProcessStuff {

    public String process(GeneralStuff gS)
    {
        return doProcess(gS);
    }

    private String doProcess(IntStuff i)
    {
        return String.format("%d", i.getValue());
    }

    private String doProcess(DoubleStuff d)
    {
        return String.format("%f", d.getValue());
    }
}


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        IntStuff iS = new IntStuff();
        DoubleStuff dS = new DoubleStuff();
        ProcessStuff pS = new ProcessStuff();

        iS.setValue(5);
        dS.setValue(23.2);

        System.out.println(pS.process(iS));
        System.out.println(pS.process(dS));
    }
}
```

This, however, doesn't work, because calling `doProcess(gS)` expects a method with a signature `doProcess(GeneralStuff gS)`.

I know I could just have two exposed polymorphic process methods in the `ProcessStuff` class, but the actual situation won't allow it because I'm working within the constraints of an existing library mechanism; this is just a contrived example for testing.

I could, of course, define `process(GeneralStuff gS)` as

```
public String process(GeneralStuff gS)
{
    if (gS instanceof IntStuff)
    {
        return doProcess((IntStuff) gS);
    }
    else if (gS instanceof DoubleStuff)
    {
        return doProcess((DoubleStuff) gS);
    }
    return "";
}
```

which works, but it seems that I shouldn't have to do that (plus, the Programming Police would skewer me for using instanceof in this way).

Is there a way that I can enforce the polymorphic calls in a better way?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

The type of dynamic dispatch you are looking for is not possible in Java without using reflection.  Java does its linking at compile time based on the declared type (so even though a method is overloaded, the actual method invoked is based on the declared type of the variable not the runtime type).

So you are left with either using instanceof as you propose, using reflection, or putting the process methods in the objects themselves (which is the "oop" way to do it, but is often not suitable or advisable).

One potential alternative is to create a map of processing objects by class, eg:

```
Map<Class<? extends GeneralStuff>,Processor> processors;

public String process(GeneralStuff stuff)
{
  Processor processor = processors.get(stuff.getClass());
  if (processor != null)
  {
    return processor.process(stuff);
  }
}

public interface Processor
{
  public String process(GeneralStuff stuff);
}

public class IntegerProcessor implements Processor
{
  public String process(GeneralStuff stuff)
  {
    return String.format("%i",((IntegerStuff) stuff).getValue());
  }
}
```

However, for your specific example, String.format takes objects as the parameters, so you could avoid this whole issue by having getValue and getFormatString methods in GeneralStuff which are overriden in the specific subclasses.

Comment: This works, and is a clever way of redirecting based on class. `Map` could also be used to direct flow to different methods within the `ProcessStuff` class, as well, I believe. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are actually on the right track, you indeed need to use reflection in this case. What you are looking for is sort of [**double dispatch**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch), because you want the dispatch to be done on the dynamic type of the stuff parameter.

This type of switching-on-dynamic-type is not as rare as you think. See for example [this javaworld tipe](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip98.html), which reflects on the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

Comment: Updated JavaWorld link: [Java Tip 98: Reflect on the Visitor design pattern](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2077602/java-tip-98--reflect-on-the-visitor-design-pattern.html)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler complains for good reason. There is no guarantee that your `GeneralStuff` object is an `IntStuff` or a `DoubleStuff`. It can be a plain `GeneralStuff` or any other extension of `GeneralStuff`, which is a case you also did not cover in your `process` method with the `instanceof` (unless returning the empty `String` was the desired behavior).

Is it not possible to move that `process` method into the `GeneralStuff` class and override it in the extensions ?

Another possible solution is to have a sort of composite `ProcessStuff` class in which you plug a `IntStuffProcess`, `DoubleStuffProcess`, ... instance . Each of those instances will still have the instanceof check to decide whether they can handle the `GeneralStuff` object passed to them, but this is at least more scalable/maintainable then one big instanceof construct

Comment: In the actual application, the parameter objects (`IntStuff`,`DoubleStuff`) are packaged as instances of `GeneralStuff` into a `Bundle` object, which is passed to another (`ProcessStuff`) object for processing, where the parameter objects are pulled out and different actions taken based on their actual types. Thus, I don't really have the option of providing overloaded process methods in `ProcessStuff` that are called directly (suggested by @βнɛƨн Ǥʋяʋиɢ), and moving the `process` method into the `GeneralStuff` is likely not an option either (suggested by you and @codegrabber).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, it's better to have overloaded `process` method in `ProcessStuff`:

```
public class ProcessStuff {

    private String process(IntStuff i) {
        return String.format("%d", i.getValue());
    }

    private String process(DoubleStuff d) {
        return String.format("%f", d.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define an GeneralStuff as an abstract class, with a doProcess method (abstract) which is filled in in the inheriting classes. This way you avoid all problems with instanceof values and such. Or you can do what is suggested by βнɛƨн Ǥʋяʋиɢ, but then you still would have to define an overload for each specific class, whereas in mine you just call it directly.

So my suggestion would be:
    public abstract class GeneralStuff {
        private int ID;

```
    public abstract String process();
}

public class IntStuff extends GeneralStuff {
    private int value;

    public void setValue(int v)
    {
        value = v;
    }

    public int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    @override
    public String process(){
        return String.format("%d", getValue());
    }
}

public class DoubleStuff extends GeneralStuff {
    private double value;

    public void setValue(double v)
    {
        value = v;
    }

    public double getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    @override
    public String process(){
        return String.format("%f", getValue());
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        IntStuff iS = new IntStuff();
        DoubleStuff dS = new DoubleStuff();
        ProcessStuff pS = new ProcessStuff();

        iS.setValue(5);
        dS.setValue(23.2);

        System.out.println(iS.process());
        System.out.println(dS.process());
    }
}
```